# aws lambda function to call internal load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb

Is there any way to call internal load balancer from a lambda function without going to internet??

I have a lambda function that need to call an internal load balancer without going to internet. Tried to put lambda function in the vpc but it cannot call the load balancer because lambda loses the internet access.

Answer (score 7):

The Lambda function will have to be configured to run in the VPC. You will need to place it in a private subnet with a NAT gateway if you want it to still have access to the Internet.

Comment: but the load balancer is internal... still lambda has to go to internet to access the internal load balancer even though lambda is in VPC??

Comment: Since the load balancer is internal, it can only be accessed from inside the VPC. It can't be accessed via the Internet. You stated that you tried adding your Lambda function to the VPC, but then it lost internet access. So it sounds like your Lambda function needs to access the internal load balancer via the VPC, and also needs to access something else that's on the Internet?

Comment: Sorry for wrong writings. my stack is like this apigateway->lambda->internalLoadBalancer.
and yes lambda need access to internal loadBalancer but lambda does not need to go internet at all

Comment: Then you should just need to add the Lambda function to the VPC, and make sure the Load Balancer's security group allows incoming requests from the Lambda function.

Comment: The answer is almost wrong. The comments are saving the answer. Please @MarkB edit the answer, the comments are the right answer.

Comment: @rios0rios0 My original answer is that the Lambda function needs to be added to the VPC. After going back and forth with the question asker in the comments, the final answer is still that the Lambda function needs to be added to the VPC. What part of the answer do you think is incorrect exactly?

Comment: @MarkB, the original question is asking how to provide internet access without network access. In your answer, you said about NAT and private subnets. This answer has nothing to do with the question. The right answer is your comment, my friend. You shouldn't put NAT and private subnets in the middle don't make sense at all. He is not asking for internet access...

Comment: @rios0rios0 the first sentence in my answer fully answers the original question. That sentence is exactly the same as what I stated in the comments. The second sentence in my answer contains the word **"if"**, which means it is optional, and only needed if their Lambda function also needs to access things outside the VPC. I didn't "put NAT and private subnets in the middle" of anything. I just added additional context to the answer since that side-effect of placing Lambda functions in a VPC is asked about on here multiple times a day.